# Transposing rows into single column excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to transpose data into a single column separate by rows with two columns with the first cell in each row staying the same.

From this:

```
Colors Red Yellow


Cars Honda Toyota
```

to

```
Colors          
         Red
         Yellow
Cars 
         Honda
         Toyota
```

With no spacing so Red should be in the next column to colors and `Honda` should be in the next column to `Cars`.

Comment: Do you really want it like that or Colors should be adjacent to red? Btw, you tagged this as VBA, but I don't see any code you've tried. Might as well include it and specifically point out where you're stuck?

Comment: Color would be cell A1, Red Cell B1, Yellow B2. Cars would be cell A3 Honda would be b3, and toyota would b4. I did figure out how to get the cells in one column but cant figure out how to space out by the cells in Column A.

Answer (score 0):

Neither VBA nor any formula may be necessary. Apply Text to Columns with space as the delimiter, then shift the second column down one row and the third down two then select blanks in the first and second columns and delete with shift cells left.

Comment: @kace And if you *Record Macro* while doing this, you'll be pretty close to what you want as well if you really need this automated.